# Will reCAPTCHA v1 still work if I get keys for reCAPTCHA v2 for the same domain?

Tags: recaptcha

We have a registration page with reCAPTCHA to (try to) limit registrations to humans. We have to upgrade to reCAPTCHA v2 before the original stops working early next year.

It looks as if the changes to our site are pretty straightforward. But we have to get a new key pair, and [keys are related to domains](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation). I'm not clear if getting new keys will invalidate the old ones.

More specifically, will getting v2 keys invalidate the keys for our existing v1 live site?

Answer (score 0):

reCAPTCHA **V1** is available until **March 31, 2018**.

Also **V1 keys** will be supported until this date!
Registering new key doesnt invalidate the old ones.

You have to [register a new key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) for reCAPTCHA **V2**. That's simple.

After, you have to change the key in your settings/script!

Instructions are here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq

Comment: How do you know that registering new key doesn't invalidate the old ones?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a new key for an existing domain will have no affect on previously registered domains. The domain validation just ensures that the key only works on a particular domain, it does not enforce that only this key works on a domain. It is valid to use different keys for different pages within the same domain.

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron. Is this documented somewhere?